# How to prevent text wrapping in DIV with textbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row that contains two DIV.  One DIV contains a textbox with % symbol that keeps wrapping to the next line.  How to prevent this?  I want textbox and % on 1 line.

```
<style type='text/css'>      
    div {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .textboxDiscountText {
        width: 100px;
    }

    .myDIV {
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>



<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px">                
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 myDIV">
                            <input type="text" id="discountpercent" name="discountpercent" class="form-control input-xs textboxDiscountText" />%
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">                            
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Discount_Type, "1") Off List
                            @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Discount_Type, "2") Net
                        </div>

                    </div>       
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I have did it, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to add `%` inside `<span class="percentage">` then you style it, Also I have deleted some css codes and class names I think you don't need them, like so in the code below:

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.percentage {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body " style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="text" id="discountpercent" name="discountpercent" class="form-control col-xs-3 col-md-3" />
        <span class="percentage">%</span>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Discount_Type, "1") Off List
        <br>@Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Discount_Type, "2") Net
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I hope that what you want and you like, Let me know if you have any qestion**

Comment: Thanks for choosing my answer as best answer, would also please vote up for my answer too, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give your textbox a width smaller than what it has now so it can accommodate for the % sign also like this

```
.myDiv {
    width:100px;
}
.myTextbox {
    width: 30px;
}

<div class='myDiv'>
<input type='textbox' class='myTextbox'> %
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS add the following

```
overflow:hidden !important;
white-space:nowrap !important;
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4L3e5t54/  This is what i get on jsfiddle and it doesnt seem to have the issue that you have mentioned.

Comment: I have just updated the answer, you may wanna try it out. I believe the problem is caused by your other css files overriding what you have.

Comment: I think it has to do with form-control class in the textbox.  When I remove it, it seems to work.

Comment: In you browser, you may wanna try disabling all the css related to your form and see which one could be causing the issue